# Ubuntu 16.04 nautilus not rendering file content as icon

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, icons

File content rendered as Icon in Ubuntu 14.04:

[image]

Whereas file content not rendered as Icon in Ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

Is there any way we can render file content as icon same as in 14.04?

Comment: I am facing the same in Ubuntu 18.04.